# Enabling SSL in tomcat 8

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, tomcat8, godaddy-api

I want to enable SSL on my website hosted from godaddy.

I am using a tomcat server and install it based on godaddy's [tutorials.](https://ph.godaddy.com/help/tomcat-generate-csrs-and-install-certificates-5239)

I successfully installed the CA certificate on my keystore:

```
pssserver, Sep 3, 2018, PrivateKeyEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): xx:xx:xx:xx: and so on
    root, Sep 3, 2018, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): xx:xx:xx:xx: and so on
    intermed, Sep 3, 2018, trustedCertEntry,
    Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): xx:xx:xx: and so on
```

And Configured the tomcat:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="C:\tomcat.jks" type="RSA" keystorePass="pss@2012" />
```

And Forced to enable the SSL on webapp:

```
<security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>ecommerce</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      
      <user-data-constraint>
          <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
      </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```

Then I restarted the server.

But after that, I cannot access my website anymore due to the last step.
I tried `https://website.com:443` but it did not load either.

What am I missing? please guide me

**PS:**
In localhost, it is working well although it gives connection not secure including the the project in localhost.

Comment: Anyone know the probleM?

Comment: check with a netstat -an if it is listening on localhost (127.0.0.1) or an interface. If listening on localhost, change your connector accordingly (but it seems correct, by default it is listening on all interfaces). If listening on an interface, disable the firewall and check.

Answer (score 1):

Following connector configuration may help

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="C:\tomcat.jks" certificateKeystorePassword="pss@2012" type=""/>
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```